# Find resources in project tree

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have a plugin project and I need a method that will find and open a file in the project where the plugin will run. 
I have in a variable the name of the file which should be inside the project. How can this be done ?

Thank you !

Comment: [Java SPI -Service Provider Interface](http://www.developer.com/java/article.php/3848881/Service-Provider-Interface-Creating-Extensible-Java-Applications.htm) is such a discovery mechanism - for _classes_. The advantage: it is fast and standard. This way XML parsers are found.

Comment: I am a little bit confused by your description. Is the file a resource inside your plug-in? Because your plug-in is only a project in your development environment. When installed it will bundled either as a jar or a directory...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a file resource inside a plug-in:

```
    Bundle bundle = Activator.getDefault().getBundle("com.your.plugin.name");
    if (bundle != null) {
        URL fileURL;
        try {
            fileURL = FileLocator.toFileURL(bundle.getEntry("/path/to/your/file/from/the/plugin/root"));
            String fileSystemPathToYourFile = fileURL.getPath());
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            // ...
        }
    }
```

Of course, you'll have to make sure the corresponding resource is properly included in your plug-in's binary build (**bin.include** property in *build.properties* file, or **Binary Build** section in the *Build* tab of the plug-in manifest editor).

If your file is a JAR, you may also have to export your plug-in as a directory (not 100% sure, may depend of what you actually do with your JAR resource - like add it to a project's build path or to a launch configuration classpath).